# select after groupby returns same records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, count, group-by

I have this query :

```
  _ctx.TestPackageReportDetails.GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.TestPackageId })
                .Select(m => new { pid = m.Key.TestPackageId, count = m.Count(i => i.Status == "Accept") })
```

This query returns 185 items with the count of each one :

[image]

But i need the number of items with `count=5` so i have this query :

```
  _ctx.TestPackageReportDetails.GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.TestPackageId })
                    .Select(m => new { pid = m.Key.TestPackageId, count = m.Count(i => i.Status == "Accept") }).Select(i => i.count == 5).Count();
```

But this returns 186 why ?
[image]

does have my code any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the grouping results using `Where`:

```
    int count = 
            _ctx.TestPackageReportDetails.GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.TestPackageId })
                              .Where(m => m.Count(i => i.Status == "Accept") == 5).Count();
```

When you need to filter, you use `.Where` and not `.Select`. Select loops through all elements and return a new form that you specify (Maybe selecting one property out of a complex object, or converting an int into a string for some reason).

But where you need to filter, you use `.Where` and you pass the condition as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you it works,could you please say why my query returns unexpected result?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar because there is no filtering in your query. Select doesn't filter, it just project each element in to a new form. So there is no place in your query where you're say: *I need only groups with count = 5*

Comment: So why it returned 186 ?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Because there are 186 rows and you used `.Select` which doesn't filter the results. Then you used `.Count` which returns the same number of results.

Answer (score 1):

Set `count=5` in where clause

```
_ctx.TestPackageReportDetails.GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.TestPackageId })
                             .Select(m => new { pid = m.Key.TestPackageId, count = m.Count(i => i.Status == "Accept") })
                             .Where(i => i.count == 5)
                             .Count();
```

Comment: Count is not accessible in where clause

Comment: @EhsanAkbar check now

Comment: @EhsanAkbar The Select clause is useless since you're returning just the Count of the results.